# Importing data from sas to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, sas, impala

I want to export one sas file from sas to hadoop sdp database.

It's exporting but taking almost 10 hrs which i want to reduce. Can anyone suggest how I can fix this.

I am using this code

```
Libname sdpuwa impala dsn=xxx pw=xxx database=xxxx;

Data sdpuwa.imapal_table;
```

Set sas_table;
Run;

Answer (score 0):

Try the `bulkload=yes` libname option.

```
libname sdpuwa impala dsn=xxx pw=xxx database=xxxx bulkload=yes;

data sdpuwa.imapal_table;
    set sas_table; 
run;
```